# Dilemma with nested Fragment:eihter "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" or "Can't retain nested fragments"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a FragmentActivity that holds a Fragment(ContainerFragment) with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter that also nested  two Fragments (a map and a list). For not getting a nullpointer after orientation change I have to set ContainerFragment setRetainInstance(true) the nested Fragments cannot be setRetainInstance(true), because there would be a exception "Can't retain nested fragments". Everything works fine with orientation change, but when i start a new Detail Fragment from the ListFragement I get "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

I searched for answers for both exceptions but nothing worked for me.

in MainActivity:

```
    containerFragment = new ContainerFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();


    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        transaction
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, containerFragment );
    }

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
```

in ContainerFragment:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    // If not set, there is a NPE on orientation change
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // load slide menu items
    mTabStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs_array);}

 public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
        case 0:

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment ) Fragment
                    .instantiate(getActivity(),
                            MapFragment .class.getName());
            return mapFragment ;

        case 1:
            ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment ) Fragment
                    .instantiate(getActivity(),
                            ListFragment .class.getName());

            return listFragment ;
        default:
            ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment ) Fragment
                    .instantiate(getActivity(),
                            ListFragment .class.getName());

            return listFragment ;

        }
```

and this method in main activity is triggerd from ListFragment and works before orientation change but not after, with "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" after transaction.commit()

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int position) {

    // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
    XYFragment xyFragment = new XYFragment ();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
    // fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can
    // navigate back
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, xyFragment);
    }

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I found a solution for not getting the npe after orientation change. I saved the instance state at onPause() of activity in SharedPreferences, so I don't need to use savedInstanceState. After that I set all Fragments to setRetainInstance(false) to get rid of the IllegalStateException. But I have to restore every nested Fragment by myself this seems to be a little inconvenient.